# dnf equivalent of rpm --replacefiles option

Tags: linux, rpm, yum, dnf

`rpm` command support `--replacefiles` option (subset of `--force`) which allows a package to overwrite files owned by another installed package.

Example:
Package 'myrpm' owns multiple files, and is already installed.
I want to install 'myrpm-custom-patch', which overwrites one of the files owned my 'mrrpm'.

```
# rpm -q myrpm
myrpm-1.0-0.x86_64

# rpm -ivh myrpm-custom-patch-2.0-0.x86_64.rpm
Verifying...                          ################################# [100%]
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
        file /usr/share/myfile from install of myrpm-custom-patch-2.0-0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package myrpm-1.0-0.x86_64

# rpm -ivh --replacefiles myrpm-custom-patch-2.0-0.x86_64.rpm
Verifying...                          ################################# [100%]
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
Updating / installing...
   1:myrpm-custom-patch-2.0-0            ################################# [100%]

# rpm -q myrpm-custom-patch-2.0-0.x86_64.rpm 
myrpm-custom-patch-2.0-0.x86_64
```

If I want to install using `dnf` command rather than `rpm` command for installing, is there any equivalent option to force replacing files owned by other packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As confirmed by redhat team, dnf does not support this.

More details here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2129808